# Guidance on laravel view composer

Tags: php, laravel

I have a header in the app layouts with a profile link. When the user clicks it, he will be redirected to his profile. I managed to do something earlier on the ads displayed on the main page, but there I used route model binding like this inside a controller:

```
public function index(User $user){
      
    $about = $user->profile()->get();
    return view ('profile.index',[
            'user' => $user,
            'about' => $about
        ]);
```

And then the route:

```
Route::get('/index/{user}', [ProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
```

If I've understood correctly, I should be using a view composer or repeat that code in many of my controllers. But do I leave the {user} in the route? And what Am I suppose to write in the composer?

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with('app', $about = $user->profile()->get());
}
```

And how will the link take the $about variable

```
<li><a href=" {{route('index', [$about]) }}">Profil</a></li>
```

Trying this returns an error, which is obvious because I'm still scratching my head to all of this

Comment: please write a more explicative title of your post

Comment: How does the title change what I need help with?

Comment: Your route accepts a `{user}`, so the `id` of the user. Why are you passing a profile instead of a user here: `<li><a href=" {{route('index', [$about]) }}">Profil</a></li>`? Why do you need the profile on every view? Maybe I don't understand what you want to do, but you are making it unnecessarily complicated in my opinion, all you probably need is `<li><a href=" {{route('index', auth()->user()) }}">Profil</a></li>`.

Comment: It's the header in the layouts.app, so it will be displayed on every page

Comment: @CarlMenger And..? From your question: _"I have a header in the app layouts with a profile link"_, why do you need the profile model on every page? you only need the authenticated user if your route for the profile accepts a user `id`.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot man! It got solved now. I jumped a bit too quick on a conclusion and overcomplicated such a simple thing.